# Deleting a list of entries LDAP PHP

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I want to be able to delete multiple different DNs (entries) from my LDAP server on a single call request by providing all the DNs as an array using PHP. How can I manage that? So far I only found a way to delete a single entry, so I can iterate over the array of the DNs and call make different requests to the server, for every DN.
I need a better and more efficient way to delete multiple entries on one call to the LDAP server please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This is a limitation of LDAP, not PHP. LDAP only allows one DN per request. So any request can only affect one object in the directory.

For example, [the LDAP documentation for a delete operation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4511#section-4.8) doesn't allow any way to specify more than one DN.

So you will have to loop through all the DNs and use PHP's [`ldap_delete`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-delete.php) on each.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (:
I saw this page:
https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/tool-usages/ldapdelete.html

and it made me think, perhaps there is a way to make the query in the link above, as a raw command, from PHP?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at [the source code for `ldapdelete`](https://github.com/openldap/openldap/blob/master/clients/tools/ldapdelete.c#L198), it just does a loop and makes one delete request per DN.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.
By the way, do you know if this is something that's about to change?

Comment: I doubt it. The LDAP specification hasn't changed since 2006. Keep in mind that deleting multiple objects in one request would introduce other complications. Say that you send 20 DN's to delete, and the 10th one fails. What should happen? Should it roll back the deletion of the first 9? Should it just stop processing them and leave the next 10 alone? Should it continue trying to delete the rest? As it is, you have control of how to handle any errors.

Comment: I see. Thank you (:
(It could work like the SQL WHERE IN, "DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <attribute> IN (a1, a2... a_n)")